# error while posting payment record to QBO via the IPP API - BILL_PAYMENT_REQUEST_BAD

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

while posting payments to QBO via the IPP SDK API, we notice that some of the payment records we are posting are failing with the following message,

```
errorCode: BILL_PAYMENT_REQUEST_BAD
reason: BILL_PAYMENT_INVALID_VENDOR_ID
```

we looked up this error code in the intuit error code list, but do not find it. Also as per the error, it seems the vendor to which we are posting the payments are not present in QBO, but on further research we found that the vendors are indeed present in QBO.

Has anyone encountered this error or has any clues as to what this error means.

Comment: Please confirm, by 'IPP SDK API', you're referring to QBO V3 REST APIs not old deprecated QBO SOAP based APIs. If it is REST APIs, then can you share the relamId and the response XML. Thanks

Comment: not sure whether it answers your question, we are using the ipp-java-devkit-2.0.6 jar.

Comment: It seems, you're using QBO V3 REST APIs and the corresponding JAVA devkit. Version should not be an issue but still I would recommend you to use the latest version(2.3.2) of the devkit.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Vendor Id in BillPayment same as that of the Bill?If not, you will get an error. I believe that might be the issue with your request.